# Android Studio - Gradle - build a CMake library with ExternalProject_Add

Tags: android, c++, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project with the following structure:

- Dependencies/CMakeLists.txt
- MainProject/CMakeLists.txt

The **Dependencies** is sub-project with a list of **ExternalProject_Add(...)** of third party libraries.

The **MainProject** is a shared library that depends on the pre-built third party libraries using FindPackage(...).

When building for Windows or Linux, the process is to build the dependencies project first, then the main project, usually from a superbuild project that includes these two using ExternalProject_Add.

How to configure Gradle to build such a library ?